# Add style-name to table of content in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, style

There is a possibility to add multiple styles to one layer.

Is there a way to add the style-name to the layername in the TOC, changing when you change to another style?

Comment: using python or QGIS interface?

Comment: using QGIS interface if possible

Comment: I think that you can change style when the other style change but multiple styles for a single layer i think that is not possible,a comples style of course but not multple styles